# How to pass some parameters from client to aidl service?

Tags: android

i am creating a simple client/service app and want to pass some parameters to the service
from client.

i referred this [two way communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331242/android-activity-remote-service-aidl-two-way-connection)
but still not clear how to solve the above problem.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) of Intent to pass parameters to a service. To get the passed parameter you can use the 'getExtra' methods of Intent into [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) of Service.